# How to convert soap object into string object in android java

Tags: java, android, android-ksoap2

I am developing application in android.I need to covert the soap object response into String.How to convert the soap object into string object in android java.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you do. Consider following is you Soap object.

```
 SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
 String resp = response.toString();        
  log.e("Response :"+resp);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below lines to convert

```
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```